# PHPExcel setAutoSize based on only row 1

Tags: php, phpexcel

Is it possible in PHPExcel to set a columns width based on only the cells in the top rows. The only examples with setAutoSize(true) sets the column with based on all data in the column. I have long descriptive texts that i don't want to auto-size, but it would be nice to have the column with adapter to header the header lengths.

This code sets with based on all rows. I want it to be based only on row 1.

```
for($col = 'A'; $col !== $worksheet->getHighestColumn(); $col++) {
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getColumnDimension($col)
    ->setAutoSize(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$columnWidthSet = ["A", "B", "C"]; //for this columns width will be bet to "50"
$width = 50;

for($col = 'A'; $col !== $worksheet->getHighestColumn(); $col++) {

    if (in_array($col, $columnWidthSet)) {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
            ->getColumnDimension($col)
            ->setAutoSize(false)
            ->setWidth($width); // width you want to apply
    } else {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
            ->getColumnDimension($col)
            ->setAutoSize(true);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. The data that will be used for the Excel export is built up dynamically in a database so I will never know which columns that are to wide to setAutoSize() on.

The best solution would be something that set column width based on the top row of the Excel file.